# Search from the menu using Selenium webdriver

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver

I'm a newbee, After entering the username/password I have an option to select a 'test' option. the first option is shown on the screen and next to it the drop down arrow. On clicking the arrow or box. A new box opens with the options to select (Test 1(default), test 2, test 3 and test4). I need to select based on the paramater set in a variable. I'm able to select the exact option by xpath settings but not been successful in using a variable to select.

The drop down is custom box - highlights the selection when mouse hovers it.

Thanks in advance

**Following is the HTML code.**

```
<div id="loginForm:selectProject_panel" class="ui-selectonemenu-panel ui-widget-content ui-corner-all ui-helper-hidden ui-shadow" style="width: 208px; display: none; top: 58px; left: 617.5px;">
<div class="ui-selectonemenu-items-wrapper" style="height:auto">
<ul class="ui-selectonemenu-items ui-selectonemenu-list ui-widget-content ui-widget ui-corner-all ui-helper-reset">
<li class="ui-selectonemenu-item ui-selectonemenu-list-item ui-corner-all" data-label="Test 1 ">Test 1</li>
<li class="ui-selectonemenu-item ui-selectonemenu-list-item ui-corner-all" data-label="Test 2 ">Test 2 </li>
<li class="ui-selectonemenu-item ui-selectonemenu-list-item ui-corner-all ui-state-highlight" data-label="Test 3">Test 3</li>
<li class="ui-selectonemenu-item ui-selectonemenu-list-item ui-corner-all" data-label="Test 4">Test 4</li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
```

WebDriver code

```
WebElement username = driver.findElement(By.id("loginForm:userLoginId"));
username.sendKeys("username");  
WebElement endKeys("Password1!");

WebElement dropdown = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*@id='loginForm:selectProject_label']"));
    dropdown.click();
//  System.out.println();

    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(15,TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    WebDriverWait waitForOptions = new WebDriverWait(driver,3);
    waitForOptions.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath(".//*[@id='loginForm:selectProject']/div[3]")));

    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(15,TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    WebElement option = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='loginForm:selectProject_panel']/div/ul/li[3]"));
    option.click();

    System.out.println("Selecting Test 3");

    WebElement button = driver.findElement(By.id("loginForm:loginButton"));
    button.click();
    System.out.println(driver.getTitle());
```

Comment: question: is it an actual dropdown? or is it a custom dropdown that someone made out of div's and/or spans?

Comment: its a custom dropdown ,,  ty

Comment: You dont need to set implicitWait before every action. The time is applicable globally for entire session once after it is set. Also explicitWait is preferred than implicitWait.

Comment: I'm sorry but what you've written is a horrible mess. You're missing the element for the password field. You're setting implicit waits multiple times instead of just once. You're writing each element as you think you need it and performing actions between them. Please read the Selenium documentation: http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/ and javadocs: http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/index.html

Comment: Thanks. There were some typos while copying over. The main issue I'm having is how to check the option using a variable. Xpath comparision doesnt seem to work

Answer (score 0):

```
String optionToSelect = "Test2"

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(@class,'ui-selectonemenu-items ui-selectonemenu') and text()='" + optionToSelect  + "') ]";
```

Comment: Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.InvalidSelectorException: The given selector .//*[ui-selectonemenu-items ui-selectonemenu-list') and text()='Test 3') ] is either invalid or does not result in a WebElement. The following error occurred:
InvalidSelectorError: Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression .//*[ui-selectonemenu-items ui-selectonemenu-list') and text()='Test 3') ] because of the following error:
- Im still getting an error .. thanks in advance

Comment: You are missing @class in the xpath that I mentioned.

Comment: String option = "Test 3";
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[contains@class,'ui-selectonemenu-items ui-selectonemenu-list') and text()='" + option + "') ]"));

Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.InvalidSelectorException: The given selector .//*[contains@class,'ui-selectonemenu-items ui-selectonemenu-list') and text()='Test 3') ] is either invalid or does not result in a WebElement. The following error occurred:InvalidSelectorError: Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression .//*[contains@class,'ui-selectonemenu-items ui-selectonemenu-list') and text()='Test 3')]

Comment: i get the same error with - driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(@class,'ui-selectonemenu-items ui-selectonemenu') and text()='" + optionToSelect  + "') ]"; . Would it be something to do with jquery ui

Comment: Give a try removing the . before //  and also make sure the element is visible before clicking.

Comment: no luck - but works perfectly ok when i give the specific xpath. WebElement option = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='loginForm:selectProject_panel']/div/ul/li[3]"));
    option.click(); 
But then i want to parameterize the option from a XML or Xl

Comment: SOME PROGRESS
String optionToSelect = "Test2"
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(@class,'ui-selectonemenu-item ui-selectonemenu-lits-item ui-corner-all ui-state-nover') and text()='" + optionToSelect  + "') ]"; 
seems to pick up the right text. But does not select or click it. How do I select or click the one selected

Comment: Just add .click() at the end of statement

Comment: Thanks a lot Yuvaraj HK. Click() was not allowing me intially with findElements (changed it to findElement). After tweaking the code a lil bit - All works well now. Thanks a bunch again